# Derivative of a function that takes a function as input

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was dealing with functional variables and came up with a quick question.
Let's define a function,
$$g(x) = x(1) - 1$$ which receives a function $x$, applies $1$ to function $x$ (i.e., $x(1)$), and subtracts $1$.
What would be the derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $x$? That is, $\dfrac{dg}{dx}$.
Let's assume function $x$ is differentiable and continuous at all points.

I know that it is not zero since $g(x)$ changes over the input function $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The functional derivative $\frac{\delta g}{\delta x}$ is defined as $A$ such that:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|g(x + h) - g(x) - A(h)|}{\| h \|} = 0$$

Here $A: x \longrightarrow x(1) $.

References:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-325-topics-in-applied-mathematics-waves-and-imaging-fall-2015/834e98a77f64597a422c205b123cd6d7_MIT18_325F15_Appendix_A.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Answer (score 0):

Your function $g$ is affine (meaning that it's of the form $x\mapsto L(x) + c$, where $L$ is a linear map and $c$ is a constant).

The derivative of a linear map is itself again. More explicitly, if $V$ and $W$ are normed vector spaces and $L : V \to W$ is linear, then $\forall v \in V$, $DL(v) = L$. In other words, the differential map of $L$ which is a map $DL: V \to \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, is the constant map $DL(v) = L$ (where $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is the vector space of all linear maps $V \to W$).

The derivative of any affine map is the derivative of the linear map which it's a translation of.

Hence, for your case, one has for all $x$, $Dg(x) = L$, where $L$ is the linear map $L(v) = v(1)$.